MySQL Workbench - Copy column from one table to another
I am trying to copy sections of a column into columns from another table in mySQL workbench, but I can't find the right command. For instance, I want to copy the first 3 rows from table 1 column 1 into my table 2 column 1, and rows 4 and 5 from tab1 col1 into tab2 col2:

The tables are already created, I want to update table2 with data from table1. I can't use the update command, because it only works to move data within the same table. I tried to use INNER JOIN but it annexes the hole table. I just want to update my second table with sections of a column from table 1. Ideally something like this:
UPDATE table2 SET table2.col1 = table1.col1 WHERE id > 1 AND id < 3
Is there any similar instruction that works for this?
Thanks in advance
SOLVED
Its necessary to disable the safety feature in MySQL to modify tables in this way. This script disables momentarily this safety feature to modify the table and enables it after the change:
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;
UPDATE table2, table1 SET table2.col1 = table1.col1 
WHERE table2.id = table1.id AND table2.id < 3; 
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 1;

